# Short idiomatic word for "low-complexity"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, technical, computing

I am looking for suggestions to convert "low-complexity" (in the context of computations or a program) into a simple, short idiomatic word or adjective (not "simple"). [EDIT] It is meant to be used in several places, and I would like to avoid repetitions with very close-by terms.

Example is use : "the polynomial predictor is of low-complexity" > "the polynomial predictor is []" or [EDIT] "this [] approach".

[EDIT] The more precise context is that of online or "real-time" computing. A task, or part of a program, should be executed in a limited amount of time. The  trade-off is: do it as good as possible, possibly complex, at the cost of other tasks that should be executed during the same period. Or at the risk that the aforementioned task cannot complete in the given amount of time. Here, low-complexity entails that the number of basic operations for the task is evaluated (somehow "bounded") and known to be able to complete.

"Low-complexity" does not mean no complexity at all. There is some, but quite tractable with little pain. Like "low-rate" does not stand for "free".

[EDIT] I thought about "scarce", or "tight", and am not unsure they apply in the context. "Efficiency" is good, it possibly does not convey the same direct "impact" to the technical reader.

[EDIT] I finally choosed a vaguer "hasty", with the acronym CHOP for "Computationally Hasty Online Prediction", which gracefully appeared before looking for the [helicopter sound](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319884/word-for-the-noise-made-by-a-helicopter).

Comment: So, a more complex version of "simple"?  Have you simply consulted a thesaurus for synonyms of "simple".  (It's quite simple -- type "synonym simple" in Google.)

Comment: I prefer to use artha http://artha.sourceforge.net/wiki/index.php/Home

Comment: But using that looks pretty complicated.

Comment: Would "tight" be usable in such a context?

Comment: You need to explain why none of *straightforward, easy, uncomplicated, uninvolved, effortless, painless, undemanding, or elementary* is suitable.

Comment: In most of my courses in Comp Sci. Very easy, simple things, were almost always referred to as "Trivial". But I'm afraid I don't have any sources that would confirm.

Comment: The answers so far seem to be recommending technical terms, if the author is looking for something to use in a research paper, the "Technical" tag might be useful to add.

Comment: In the context of a program implementation or algorithm that performs well, I would suggest: efficient, elegant, or concise (if brevity is a component of "low-complexity") Noting that efficient, elegant, and concise solutions are not necessarily easily: comprehensible, accessible, or approachable. Somewhere in between the two sides of "low-complexity" might be 'effective.'

Comment: Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_%28complexity%29 and here: https://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en#hl=en&q=define+%22low-complexity%22+mathematics  HTH

Comment: @HotLicks & 7 upvoters It's not as simple as it looks. See the comment above, too.

Comment: @Corra efficient is a good word, since it conveys some quantitative information. Efficient can for instance both mean: fast, or with quality results

Comment: It is not clear what it is you want to convey. The opposite of *complex* is *simple*. If you want to emphasize the simpleness of the task, I suggest ***trivial***. However, if you want to emphasize that the time bounds of the task are known, you can use either ***deterministic***, ***measurable***, or your own suggestion of ***bounded***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [**Order-1** or **low order**](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/3.COMPLEXITY.html). You can even use **O1** is you want to play with the cool kids.

This means that the algorithm scales linearly with the input. So, it is the "most scalable" type of simple algorithm, in that **O2** algorithms require something in proportion to the square of the number of inputs.

It doesn't mean there are zero operations.

**O1** computations can still be very large, but are far simpler than **On**, **n>1**. That doesn't argue against using the term, it just argues that not every problem has a "simple" solution, but **O1** are, in many senses, the "simplest" one can find.

Comment: I thought  about saying this, but "low-order" is two words. Also, OP is not talking about the polynomial... he's talking about it's "predictor".

Comment: @jimm101 Indeed, this predictor is somehow quadratic with low   constants. But the polynomial can be quartic or qunntic. Like 01  anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think there was another answer here at one point that said "incomplex". I do not believe that this is the word you are looking for if you are writing a mathematical paper about polynomials. I would recommend the term:

**smooth**

See [definitions #4, #5, and #7](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/smooth?s=t).

The reason that I would suggest to use the word *smooth* is because I have already seen it used numerous times regarding the calculation of polynomials. Although [this paper](http://this) does not exactly reflect what you are writing about, it will give you an idea of how the term *smooth* can be used in mathematics as a substitute for saying "not-complex" or "simple". The term *smooth* here is used for the *smoothing* of polynomials in the field of encryption. I am not sure how this will sound in your sentence (maybe it will confuse things mathematically, I am an engineer not a mathmetician) but this is the closest thing I could find.

Comment: Complexity refers to the number of operations the algorithm performs for a given input. Smoothness refers to the rate of change of change (2nd derivative). They aren't related in any obvious way.

Comment: @jimm101 I guess I thought that the OP was NOT asking for a "mathematical" term and just a general idiomatic word to describe "low-complexity". If they were actually looking for a mathematical word, then that was my misunderstanding. I also kind of thought that based on the usage in some papers I have seen for science/engineering you could massage the word to make it fit for what the OP is trying to say.