# What word could be used to describe the sound of hovercraft propellers?

Tags: single-word-requests

In a composition that I am writing, I am describing the sound of a very large hovercraft, namely its propellers. I've listened to a video of one such hovercraft, and it's not a whir, or a buzz, or a drone. I just can't quite put my finger on what to call it. The best I thought of was "roar", but I think there's probably a better word than that.

I suggest you have a look at the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nWcctrrkG1E) (Skip to about 15 seconds in) and see if you can think of a word to describe the sound.

Sample sentence: *"I yelled under the ______ of the three vast propellers."*

Comment: "My yelling was futile against the roar of the three vast propellers"   I too, heard it as a roar.

Comment: Roar sounds good to me. Googling for **hovercraft roar** finds lots of results in books, web sites and newspapers.

Comment: I will observe that with many such vehicles -- hovercraft, helicopters, small prop planes, etc -- the actual sound is much less unique than ones romantic imagination wishes it to be.  Helicopters in flight, eg, are essentially indistinguishable from ordinary prop planes.

Comment: The hover blades,underneath, seem to whoosh, while the propulsion blades roar, or have a roaring beat to them. -Those blades are slightly out of sync, so you hear beat frequencies too.

Comment: Seemingly closely related: [Word for the noise made by a helicopter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319884/word-for-the-noise-made-by-a-helicopter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for the noise made by a helicopter?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319884/word-for-the-noise-made-by-a-helicopter)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thrum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thrum)

> Make a continuous rhythmic humming sound.
>
> ‘the boat's huge engines thrummed in his ears’

Comment: I think "roar" would be the word of choice.  "Thrum" connotes a lower-volume humming sound.  If you're on the quay, the boat's engines might seem to thrum, but if you're in the boat's engine room, you would probably say they were roaring.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I’d describe the sound of a helicopter…
Wyump wyump wyump
…but if you’re looking for a higher frequency version I’d say…
Zwiss zwiss zwiss

If you’re looking for a non-onomatopoeia descriptor I’d say…
“Whirring hum”

Comment: This seems to be an answer to a different question.